# Pseudo-inverse of matrix representation is matrix representation of pseudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map on finite dimensional inner product spaces $V,W$.
  Let $\beta,\gamma$ be ordered (orthonormal?) bases for $V,W$ respectively.

Is it necessarily the case that
$[T^{\dagger}]^{\beta}_{\gamma} = ([T]^{\gamma}_{\beta})^{\dagger}$ ?

If so, how does one prove this result? And do we require the bases to be orthonormal?

Note: $\dagger$ denotes the pseudoinverse (Moore-Penrose generalized inverse) of a matrix/linear map.

Comment: I'm familiar with the definition of the pseudoinverse for a matrix, but please remind me how we define the pseudoinverse for an arbitrary linear mapping?

Comment: @Patch: the definition is a straightforward copy of the matrix case; proving it exists or calculating it less so. But basically you just assert that it's the unique operator $T^\dagger$ satisfying $T T^\dagger T = T$, $T^\dagger T T^\dagger = T^\dagger$, and with both $T T^\dagger$ and $T^\dagger T$ Hermitian.  If T has a closed range (guaranteed for finite dimensions), this will exist.